# How to monitor Job Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have a lot of Scheduled Jobs and I don't monitor it. Incidentially I realized that one of my Job has ‘Last Run Result’ value (0x1) instead of expected “The operation completed successfully . (0x0)”. When I checked it really failed to executed.
Well ... now I want to somehow monitor result of Tasks. Obviously I could check Job Scheduler myself for ‘Last Run Result’ value (0x1) but I'm asking if you have any suggestion how I could do it programmatically.
All my scripts in those Jobs are written in Python but likely I'll need to know the place where I could get information about that 'Last Run Result'
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to handle this thread but I'd suggest to delete it ... because when I asked for help I needed it but now I don't need it anymore. I figured out that I could implement my task by writting python script that checks logging out for sequence of events. It works for me. I believe you could close/delete the thread.

Comment: Please close the ticket for me since it's not valid for me anyway.